# Express Session Middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am doing the Coursera course on Server-Side Development and I have followed the instructions precisely.  I keep getting this error, however.  There are no relevant posts on their Discussion platform, and I cannot seem to debug because (if you see below) the trace is solely referring to files in the node_modules folder that are established upon initialization of the project as a node project.  Thus, I am stuck.  Presumably there is "something" wrong with my code, but since the trace is not referring to anything I coded, I am lost.  I also thought that perhaps I failed to install express, but I have tried reinstalling as per instructions in the course and that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Has anyone encountered this specific error when creating a Node.js project and, if so, what did you do to solve?

Login sessions require session support. Did you forget to use `express-session` middleware?

This is the app.js code:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
const session = require('express-session');
var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);
var passport = require('passport');
var authenticate = require('./authenticate');
var config = require('./config');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var dishRouter = require('./routes/dishRouter');
var leaderRouter = require('./routes/leaderRouter');
var promoRouter = require('./routes/promoRouter');
const uploadRouter = require('./routes/uploadRouter');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');

const Dishes = require('./models/dishes');

const url = config.mongoUrl;
const connect = mongoose.connect(url);

connect.then((db) => {

  console.log('Connected correctly to the server.');

}, (err) => {console.log(err); });

var app = express();

// Secure traffic only
app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.secure) {
    return next();
  }
  else {
    res.redirect(307, 'https://' + req.hostname + ':' + app.get('secPort') + req.url);
  }
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());  // FOund this in the Forum not Given Code

// Note that these two mountings occur before authentication
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// Authentication is now completed
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// This is where the mounting occurs
app.use('/dishes', dishRouter);
app.use('/promotions', promoRouter);
app.use('/leaders', leaderRouter);
app.use('/imageUpload',uploadRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

This is the index.js file:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    
    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
    });

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Please show the relevant portions of your code that initialize the `express-session` middleware which is infrastructure that is needed for the Passport login module to function properly. That's what the error message is trying to tell you.

Comment: This is the latest version the instructor wanted us to use:

Comment: const session = require('express-session');
var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);

Comment: Can't help without seeing a LOT more code.  Please add all relevant code to your question.  Include all server initialization and middleware code.

Comment: Part of the difficulty is . . . I am not really sure what else is relevant.  There are about 30 different files here.  The code I sent is in the app.js file.  The code below is in the index.js file:
'''var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
 '''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/session-file-store#express-or-connect-integration) for `session-file-store`, the proper initialization is this:

```
const session = require('express-session');
const FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);
 
const fileStoreOptions = {};
 
app.use(session({
    store: new FileStore(fileStoreOptions),
    secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
```

You seem to be missing the `app.use()` part that actually initializes express-session.